# How can I turn the power of an external circuit on and off?

Tags: transistors, switches, gpio

I have a circuit of batteries which power some good old light bulbs.

I now want to turn the light bulbs on and off through GPIO.

Unfortunately I have no idea how this would look like. Which electronic parts could act as a mechanical switch when a small voltage is on them without having the danger that the voltage goes on to the GPIO controller?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to work with: which voltage, what kind of 'GPIO controller' do you use, do you have a circuit diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the "good old light bulbs" are the sort that run off a 6V torch battery or the sort that plg into a 120 V AC or 230 V AC power line.

In the former case, you can use a FET or BJT rated for the  voltage and current needed by the bulb.

In the latter case use a purpose designed relay rated for the voltage and current to be switched.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the relay can be safe in either case, though its coil uses more power than the FET would.

Comment: Yeah, a relay itself looks more convenient to me but I think that the GPIO output would not be enough to power the relay. However thanks for the help!